# How to get updated contents of HTMLTable in Coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My problem is when I delete a row from shopping cart (ASP.NET MVC MUSIC STORE) I always get the same number of rows when page is refreshed.

I have 4 rows in the HTMLTable (1 header, 1 bottom row for Total and 2 rows of products, When I delete the row 'Greatest Hits' by finding the a row using function 'FindRowForProduct2('Greatest Hits')', Now my table has only one row of product with Album Name 'Greatest Hits I', When I call a function IsProductInCart('Greatest Hits'), FindRowforProduct2 shows 4 rows including the product 'Greatest Hits' which has already deleted. how may I get updated table control that has only 3 rows header,bottom and 1 row of the product. see my code below.

```html
        private HtmlControl FindRowForProduct2(string productName)
        {
            var rowCount = this.ShoppingCartTable.RowCount;
            Debug.WriteLine("row Cound: " + rowCount); // return 4

            for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
            {                
                HtmlControl productRow = ShoppingCartTable.GetRow(i);
                Debug.WriteLine("Row{0}: {1}", i, productRow.InnerText);
                HtmlCell cell = new HtmlCell(productRow);
                cell.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.InnerText, productName);
                if(cell.TryFind())
                {
                    return productRow;
                }

            }
            return new HtmlRow();
            
        }
                                     
        private HtmlTable ShoppingCartTable
        {
            get
            {

                HtmlTable shoppingCartTable = new HtmlTable(_browserWindow);
                shoppingCartTable.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
                shoppingCartTable.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlTable.PropertyNames.InnerText, "Album Name", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

                return shoppingCartTable;
            }
        } 
 
        public bool IsProductInCart(string productName)
        {
            return FindRowForProduct2(productName).TryFind();
        }
```

Comment: Is this the example from pluralsight?

Comment: yes, I have recently attended a course, but incase of deleting a product I'm unable to get updated table.

Comment: it is possible that the delete row actually just collapses the row instead of actually deleting the data, in that case you should check if the row's visibility property or expanded (if available)

Comment: you are right this application hiding the object instead removing it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're calling the same instance of the table object you created.  Try using:

```
    private HtmlControl FindRowForProduct2(string productName)
    {
        HtmlTable currentTable = 
            (HtmlTable)this.ShoppingCartTable.FindMatchingControls()[0];

        var rowCount = currentTable.RowCount;
        Debug.WriteLine("row Cound: " + rowCount); // return 4

        for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
        {                
            HtmlControl productRow = currentTable.GetRow(i);
            Debug.WriteLine("Row{0}: {1}", i, productRow.InnerText);
            HtmlCell cell = new HtmlCell(productRow);
            cell.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.InnerText, productName);
            if(cell.TryFind())
            {
                return productRow;
            }

        }
        return new HtmlRow();

    }
```

This will force the engine to overwrite your original object with a new instance, getting the latest state from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out why row was not removing from the table, In Music MVC Story app, they applied the *sytle="display: none;"* and object was hiding in table.

Now I have fixed my function as follows and working absolutely fine.

```
    private HtmlRow FindRowForProduct2(string productName)
    {

        var rowCount = this.ShoppingCartTable.RowCount;
        Debug.WriteLine("row Count: " + rowCount);

        for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
        {                
            HtmlControl productRow = ShoppingCartTable.GetRow(i);

            HtmlCell cell = new HtmlCell(productRow);
            cell.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.InnerText, productName);
            if (!productRow.ControlDefinition.Contains("style=\"display: none;\""))
            {
                if (cell.TryFind())
                {
                    return (HtmlRow)productRow;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: as i suggested in the comment above.. nice catch though